# how to omit imports using .coveragerc in coverage.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests, coverage.py

I am using nosetests --with-coverage to test and see code coverage of my unit tests. The class that I test has many external dependencies and I mock all of them in my unit test.

When I run nosetests --with-coverage, it shows a really long list of all the imports (including something I don't even know where it is being used).

I learned that I can use .coveragerc for configuration purposes but it seems like I cannot find a helpful instruction on the web.

My questions are..
1) In which directory do I need to add .coveragerc? How do I specify the directories in .coveragerc? My tests are in a folder called "tests"..
/project_folder
/project_folder/tests

2)It is going to be a pretty long list if I were to add each in omit= ...
What is the best way to only show the class that I am testing with the unittest in the coverage report?

It would be nice if I could get some beginner level code examples for .coveragerc. Thanks.

Comment: i always just use `--cover-package` along with `--with-coverage`.  have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to direct coverage.py's focus is to use the `source` option, usually `source=.` to indicate that you only want to measure code in the current working tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `--cover-package=PACKAGE` option. For example:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=module_you_are_testing
```

See http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/cover.html for details.